# How do I implement Rich Snippets on a product/service that has monthly fee?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

Using these but it's not validating:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Product</h1>
  <span itemprop="description">Product
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    Prices start at <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="PHP" />Php
    <span itemprop="price">1799.00 (monthly)
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: How/where do you validate it and what does the validator report?

Comment: I'm trying to use rich snippets so it would show up in search results, but all the examples I've seen are for prices and price ranges only. Tried to include the "monthly" text. The validator doesn't give any specific error, but the preview only shows the price, and not the monthly text.

Comment: I updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27035954/1591669): there’s a solution for specifying monthly fees.

Answer (score 7):

To represent subscription costs (for an `Offer`), you could use the [`UnitPriceSpecification` type](http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification) and its [`unitCode` property](http://schema.org/unitCode).

The `unitCode`’s value can be a UN/CEFACT Common Code, where `MON` is the code for month.

In Microdata, this could look like:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

    <div itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification">
      Prices start at <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="PHP" />Php
      <span itemprop="price">1799.00</span>
      <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="MON">(monthly)
    </div>

  </div>    

</div>
```

Comment: (As in your example you are saying that prices "start at" …, you might want to use [`minPrice`](http://schema.org/minPrice)/[`maxPrice`](http://schema.org/maxPrice); but it’s probably better to make this explicit and have several `Offer` items with exact prices.)

Comment: Thanks. I really like this approach but it would be nice to have an example reference (like on Google on Schema.org site) to confirm this is the way to go.