# Is there a Schema.org type for SaaS or subscriptions?

Tags: saas, schema.org

We sell a Software as a Service with a monthly subscription, I’m trying to figure out if we can provide metadata through Schema.org’s specifications.
I have been considering [products](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products), but it doesn’t seem to support subscription costs.

For products, Google seems to have e-commerce physical object-type stuff in mind.

There is also [Software applications](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products), but that seems to be made for downloadable software rather than web-apps.

What should I use?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are different possible perspectives:

- It’s a [`SoftwareApplication`](http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication) (or the more specific [`WebApplication`](http://schema.org/WebApplication), maybe with [`browserRequirements`](http://schema.org/browserRequirements)).
- It’s a [`Service`](http://schema.org/Service) with a [`ServiceChannel`](http://schema.org/ServiceChannel)+[`serviceUrl`](http://schema.org/serviceUrl).
- It’s a [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product) and/or an [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) (both include services).

  (It *is* possible to [specify subscription costs in Schema.org](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27035954/1591669).)

You might want to use only one or multiple types of these, depending on your understanding of the SaaS, and what metadata you want to provide.

Answer (score 26):

I was struggling with this too. We develop SEO tools, web based applications and have 3 plans, each in annual and monthly version, and also a free plan. I totally recommend you to include also a  free plan as it will display in SERP as a FREE product. If you don't the lowest price will display in SERP. However I have end up with the following solution:

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "WebApplication",
            "@id": "kwfinder",
            "applicationCategory": "BusinessApplication",
            "name": "KWFinder - find logtail keywords with low seo difficulty",
            "operatingSystem": "all",
            "browserRequirements": "Requires Javascript and HTML5 support",
            "url": "https://app.kwfinder.com",
            "screenshot": "https://kwfinder.com/images/kwfinder-big.png",
            "aggregateRating": {
              "@type": "AggregateRating",
              "ratingValue": "4.53",
              "reviewCount": "3"
            },
            "offers": {
                "@type": "AggregateOffer",
                "offeredBy": {
                  "@type": "Organization",
                  "name":"mangools"
                },
                "highPrice": "469.00",
                "lowPrice": "0",
                "offerCount": "6",
                "priceCurrency": "USD",
                "priceSpecification": [
                    {
                        "@type": "UnitPriceSpecification",
                        "price": "0.00",
                        "priceCurrency": "USD",
                        "name": "mangools FREE subscription"
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "UnitPriceSpecification",
                        "price": "469.00",
                        "priceCurrency": "USD",
                        "name": "mangools Premium annual subscription",
                        "referenceQuantity": {
                            "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
                            "value": "1",
                            "unitCode": "ANN"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "UnitPriceSpecification",
                        "price": "49",
                        "priceCurrency": "USD",
                        "name": "mangools Premium monthly subscription",
                        "referenceQuantity": {
                            "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
                            "value": "1",
                            "unitCode": "MON"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "creator": {
              "@type":"Organization",
              "@id":"#organization",
              "url":"https://mangools.com/",
              "name":"mangools",
              "logo":{
                "@type":"ImageObject",
                "url":"https://mangools.com/mangools-logo.png",
                "width":"700px",
                "height":"235px"
              }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

With this code you will get something like this:

[image]

**Please note that if you markup product on a main homepage,** it will not appear in SERP. [Google accepts structured data only for leaf pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600500/google-rich-snippets-not-working/31616800#31616800).

I also wrote a [quick case study](https://mangools.com/blog/fail-win-rich-snippets-serp-2-days-case-study/) about this problem on our blog.

Comment: Since your answer is coming up on the eight-year mark, I was wondering if you had any updates you would care to make? Are you still using this approach?