# Google Rich Snippets Not Working

Tags: seo, schema.org, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I'm working on a website for a friend (www.texasfriendlydds.com) and am trying to give them an edge with Rich Snippets that Google allegedly loves. It's a defensive driving school with 10 locations in the Austin area. I've placed the schema.org code within the address of each location, but while searching 'defensive driving austin' - I do not see any of the locations listed. I have 10 of the following code for each location(different address for each):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  <span itemprop="name">Texas Friendly Defensive Driving</span><br />
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <span itemprop="streetAddress">13201 Ranch Road 620</span><br />
      <span itemprop="addressLocality">Austin</span> <span itemprop="addressRegion">TX</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">78750</span>    
    </div>

    <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
      <span itemprop="ratingValue">4.6</span> stars - based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">24</span> reviews
    </div>

    Free meal w/ <span itemprop="priceRange">$40 tuition</span><br /><br />

    <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Thursdays 3:30pm - 9:30pm"><b>Thursdays 3:30pm - 9:30pm</b><br />
</div>
```

In addition, at the bottom of the page, I aggregate all the reviews in attempt to get organic search rich snippet star-ratings to no avail. I've compared my code directly with the following site:
- http://www.microdatagenerator.com/aggregate-rating-schema-generator/

They were exactly the same (minus the values). You can find their snippets by Googling 'aggregate rating schema' and find the 2nd listing with rich snippet stars and 956 ratings. At one point I read that you need to show proof of your ratings, but this site doesn't do that and they have them.

I've used the Google Structured Data Testing Tool (https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) and everything comes out peachy. So why in the world am I not seeing any results from this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We (Google) don't accept rich snippets for homepages; rich snippet annotations should be placed on leaf pages.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for the info. What about the structured data that displays address, pricing, and hours? Leaf pages for each one as well?

Comment: Yes, most (I guess it's more like "all") rich snippets need to be on leaf pages. If the SDTT validates your markup and the rich snippets don't show up, chances are the markup is leaf pages only.

Comment: What about one-page websites , they are alot nowadays ... i.e there are no leaf pages in them , its all in one page :(