# Schema.org markup for a product with an upfront price *and* a subscription

Tags: html, e-commerce, schema.org, markup, microdata

I recently stumbled upon a bit of a markup conundrum:
I’m building a product page for a mobile carrier that features a single smartphone that you can buy at a discount *only if* you get two subscriptions with it.

So, I’ve got 3 mandatory prices to display on that single page: the price of the smartphone you have to pay *upfront*, and the monthly prices of the two additional subscriptions you *have to* get in order to buy the smartphone.

How would one go about structuring the Schema.org markup of such a product page?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show (include as markup example) what you’ve tried?

Comment: I think that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49322528/1821792) to a similar question is applicable for you.