# Structured markup adding models to product data

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I have a question regarding the correct way of using structured markup (Microdata / Schema.org) for the situation where I have a main overview product and then, within that, a list of models with separate prices and a custom attribute.

Simplified example:

```html
<div class="mainproduct" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
 <h1 itemprop="name">Product Name</h1>
 <p itemprop="description">Lorem ipsum my description oh yay all hear this.</p>
 <div class="modelslist" >
   <div class="model" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProductModel">
     <h2 itemprop="name">Model A</h2>
     <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
         <meta itemprop="price" content="£123" />
         <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PriceSpecification">
             <span itemprop="price">£123</span>
             <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />
             <meta itemprop="valueAddedTaxIncluded" content="false" />
         </span>
     </span>
     <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
          <meta itemprop="name" content="readability" />
          <span itemprop="value">325</span>
     </span>                                                                        
   </div>
   <div class="model" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProductModel">
     <h2 itemprop="name">Model B</h2>
     <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
         <meta itemprop="price" content="£456" />
         <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PriceSpecification">
             <span itemprop="price">£456</span>
             <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />
             <meta itemprop="valueAddedTaxIncluded" content="false" />
         </span>
     </span>
     <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
          <meta itemprop="name" content="readability" />
          <span itemprop="value">325</span>
     </span>  
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Q1.  Is it correct to specify a price and then a price specification?  Without the meta price, the Google Structured Data Testing Tool warns that "offer" is empty.

Q2.  How do I specify custom data shown by "thingymabob". I am assuming it is something to do with "additionalProperty" but the testing tool complains that "additionalProperty" is not recognised by Google for an object of type ProductModel.    (Although it seems it would be from http://schema.org/ProductModel)

---

**UPDATE**

Ok so here is the update, the pricing is now all tickity-boo and the addition of the itemprop="model", itemprop="offers"  and itemprop="priceSpecification" all complete the correct nesting.

```html
<div class="mainproduct" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
   <h1 itemprop="name">Product Name</h1>
   <p itemprop="description">Lorem ipsum my description oh yay all hear this.</p>
   <div class="modelslist" >
       <div class="model" itemprop="model" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProductModel">
           <h2 itemprop="name">Model A</h2>
           <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
             <meta itemprop="price" content="123" />
             <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />
             <span itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification">
                £<span itemprop="price">123</span>
                <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />
                <meta itemprop="valueAddedTaxIncluded" content="false" />
             </span>
          </span>
          <span itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
              <meta itemprop="name" content="readability" />
              <span itemprop="value">325</span>
          </span>                                                                        
    </div>
    <div class="model" itemprop="model" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProductModel">
        <h2 itemprop="name">Model B</h2>
        <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
           <meta itemprop="price" content="456" />
           <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />
           <span itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification">
               £<span itemprop="price">456</span>
               <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />
               <meta itemprop="valueAddedTaxIncluded" content="false" />
          </span>
       </span>
       <span itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
          <meta itemprop="name" content="readability" />
          <span itemprop="value">325</span>
      </span>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That just leaves the issue of adding additional properties to models.  It would appear from http://schema.org/ProductModel  that additionalProperty  should be ok - is it just Google that currently does not allow it?  It does return this message in the testing tool:  "The property additionalProperty is not recognised by Google for an object of type ProductModel."  Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Just for information:   have tried <span itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">

Comment: I [tried to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30714350/1591669) your Q1. I think Q2 is not so closely related that they should belong in the same question. Would you agree? In that case, you might want to create a separate question for Q2.

Comment: I guess it is related to me as I was trying to resolve one situation but yes, I did think at the point of writing Q1  and Q2 that I probably should not do that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a pity that Google Search ([according to their documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products)) only supports [`price`](http://schema.org/price), not [`priceSpecification`](http://schema.org/priceSpecification). I’m sure that that they’ll support it in the future (if it’s not already the case, albeit undocumented).

Providing both properties seems to be a suitable solution, especially in such simple cases where you don’t have, [e.g., a monthly fee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27035954/1591669).

About your markup regarding the price:

- the [`priceSpecification`](http://schema.org/priceSpecification) property (to reference the [`PriceSpecification`](http://schema.org/PriceSpecification)) is missing
- instead of `PriceSpecification` you might want to use [`UnitPriceSpecification`](http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification), as [it says for `PriceSpecification`](http://schema.org/PriceSpecification):

  > Typically, only the subclasses of this type are used for markup.
- the `price` value should not contain the currency; use [`priceCurrency`](http://schema.org/priceCurrency) instead

So your markup could look like:

```html
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <meta itemprop="price" content="123" />
  <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />
  <span itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification">
    £<span itemprop="price">123</span>
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />
    <meta itemprop="valueAddedTaxIncluded" content="false" />
  </span>
</span>
```

(Note that you should also use a property to reference this `Offer` from the product it belongs to.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time on this.  Actually the way that I have done the itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PriceSpecification"   apparently passes the google test but the price specifications do not appear to be related to the models in the results. Will try your UnitPriceSpecification  approach.

You are correct about the currency symbol so I will alter that.  So that does leave the tricky part two bit

Comment: actually your point about itemprop="priceSpecification" has made me realise I have left off a load of itemprop attributes elsewhere:  model, and offers.  I think it also nudges me in the write direction to answer 2 myself. Also the joys of a new day and a clearer head makes these things easier to spot.

Comment: Actually question 2 is still valid but, to me anyway, looks like a lack of Google support rather than an issue with the markup.

Comment: @JonHolland: Yeah, `additionalProperty` was [added recently](http://schema.org/docs/releases.html#v2.0) and Google is is known to take some time to update their Structured Data Testing Tool. There are [alternatives for checking Microdata (+ Schema.org)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13674/60 "Online Microdata parser").

Comment: Marking as accepted answer - I think we got there between us :)